# How to pg_restore one table and its schema from a Postgres dump?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres, pg-dump, pg-restore

I am having some difficulties with restoring the schema of a table. I dumped my Heroku Postgres db and I used pg_restore to restore one table from it into my local db (it has more than 20 tables). It was successfully restored, but I was having issues when I tried to insert new data into the table.

When I opened up my database using *psql*, I found out that the restored table is available with all the data, but its schema has zero rows. Is there anyway I could import both the table and its schema from the dump? Thank you very much.

This is how I restored the table into my local db:

```
pg_restore -U postgres --dbname my_db --table=message latest.dump
```

Edit:

I tried something like this following the official docs, but it just gets blocked and nothing happened. My db is small, no more than a couple of megabytes and the table's schema I am trying to restore has no more than 100 row.

```
pg_restore -U postgres --dbname mydb --table=message --schema=message_id_seq latest.dump
```

Comment: By "schema", do you mean "table data", a sequence, or the object that is created by `CREATE SCHEMA`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As a more general answer (I needed to restore a single table from a *huge* backup), you may want to take a look at this post: https://thequantitative.medium.com/restoring-individual-tables-from-postgresql-pg-dump-using-pg-restore-options-ef3ce2b41ab6

```
# run the schema-only restore as root
pg_restore -U postgres --schema-only -d new_db /directory/path/db-dump-name.dump

# Restore per table data using something like
pg_restore -U postgres --data-only -d target-db-name -t table_name /directory/path/dump-name.dump
```

Answer (score 0):

## Restore a single schema qualified table

Building on [@Haroldo_OK's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65106893/526860); to specify the schema that the table belongs to use the `--schema` option when restoring the data:

```bash
# Restore only the schema (data definitions), not data into the database new_db
# which is assumed to already exist
pg_restore -U postgres --schema-only -d new_db /directory/path/db-dump-name.dump

# Restore the data for the schema_name.table_name table in the new_db database
pg_restore -U postgres --data-only -d new_db --schema schema_name --table table_name /directory/path/dump-name.dump
```

If the Postgres cluster that you are restoring into is a different cluster from the one the backup was made from then the cluster you are restoring into might not have the group/login roles of the one the backup was made from. In this instance you can choose to specify the `--no-owner` and `--no-privileges` options which prevent restoration of object ownership and access privileges (grant/revoke commands).

[pg_restore documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html).

Answer (score -3):

From the Heroku DevCenter [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#using-the-cli)

> Heroku Postgres is integrated directly into the Heroku CLI and offers
>   many helpful commands that simplify common database tasks

You can check [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#local-setup) if your environment is correctly configured.

In this way, you can use the Heroku CLI [pg:pull](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-pull) command to pull remote data from a Heroku Postgres database to a local database on your machine.

For example:

```
$ heroku pg:pull HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAGENTA mylocaldb --app sushi
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the specific question. Using `pg:pull` will restore the entire database locally whereas OP wants to restore a single table.

Comment: @RangerRanger It’s true, but I’ve suggested using directly the Heroku tools for two reason: 1) the DB is only a “couple of MB” then basically there are no differences - I wouldn’t have suggested otherwise  2) if an user does not have much experience on PG dump/restore this could be an easier and safer way for him

Comment: @Andrea, I have already pulled my remote database into my local one; and I have pg_restored the desired table, the problem is with the sequence table, they don't get restored with their tables automatically. I had to edit the sequence table to match the data table manually. Not the best approach but worked. Thanks for your answer.